# java-Rotating image in it's position

Tags: java, android, graphics

I've a listView and each row has an icon .

I want when I click on the row , the image begin to rotating around in the center of its self , Like a progressbar .

I'v searched , But I really don't know anything about graphic in java and it's all I need from it !!

thanks

Comment: If your icons are bitmaps, you'd need a set of (at least) 7 additional bitmaps in rotated position (45°, 90°,...). And they won't look as good. And reserving the place for that requires 40% more in both directions. - I'm not sure whether this a good idea. Blinking would be easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you define a xml file `list_item.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can use `RotateAnimation` with different attributes to get the style you want.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        Animation rotateAnimation = new       
        RotateAnimation(0f,360f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f); 
        rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(3);
        rotateAnimation.setDuration(3000);              
        imageView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);        
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help , is there any way I stop the rotation by myself ? for example , if I click on a button or I leave the activity , It stops rotating immediately?

Comment: You can apply `imageView.clearAnimation()` on all the image views in the list to stop the animation.